# OWin Startup attribute not found error on Web API REST Request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have a Web API project along with the built in help website. When I start up the project locally, the help website home page displays no problem. But when I send a REST POST request to an API controller using fiddler, I get the following response.

```
The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
 - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
 - No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.
```

I have tried to solve using the suggestions in the error message but no joy.

It works OK on the test server.

Can anyone suggest why this error is returned only on a REST request and not when the help website starts up and any tips on how to solve?

Comment: Do you have start up class? If no - check this article http://www.gregpakes.co.uk/post/owin-series-part-2-katana

Comment: Yes I have a class like that - although I dont know why it is still looking for it because I set <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" /> in web.config. The startupo class does get hit when the help website runs but not on a REST request.

Comment: Do you have mix of Wep API and, say, MVC? May your need to exclude your Web API routing from MVC. (This is only consideration, but i had the same problem with MVC site having WCF service)